# can prefix and post be used at the same time on a variable in c

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h> 

int main()
{
    char *q;
    char *p = "sweta";
    q = ++p++;
    printf("%s", q);
}
```

what is the output is this program valid as it gives an error of l value required.

Comment: return type of main should be `int`.

Comment: As it gives you a compiler error it is therefore not valid, unless you are alleging a compiler bug.

Answer (score 6):

`q = ++p++;` this won't even compile in C or in C++

Post increment operator has higher [precedence](http://www.difranco.net/compsci/C_Operator_Precedence_Table.htm) than pre increment operator

So `q= ++p++` is interpreted as `q = ++(p++)`. Now the post increment operator returns an `rvalue` expression whereas the preincrement operator requires its operand to be an `lvalue`.

`ISO C99 (Section 6.5.3.1/1)`

`Constraints`

> The  operand  of  the  preﬁx  increment  or  decrement  operator  shall  have  qualiﬁed  or unqualiﬁed real or pointer type and shall be a **modiﬁable lvalue**.

Comment: Unless, of course, you overload `operator++`: for instance, it's perfectly legal, given `std::vector<T> v`, to say `*++v.begin()` to get the second element. Not sure why you would, but I suppose there's a situation for everything.

Comment: The question has been tagged C.

Answer (score 3):

This can't be done, as you can't increment a temporary object.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use prefix/postfix operators more than one time on a variable. This is because the operator returns a **copy** of the original variable, so using another operator on the copy would not change the original variable. C/C++ do not allow this to prevent confusion.

If you want to increment the variable by two while copying the new value to `q`, you can use `q=(p+=2);` instead of `q=++p++;`

Comment: that wouldn't follow the original intent, as it would (supposedly) pre-increment, assign, then post-increment.

Answer (score 1):

Don't try too clever and push the language where it is not supposed to go. 
It will bite you someday. Or bite your customer and they will bite you.

Just be sane and code it this way:

```
#include <stdio.h> 

int main()
{
    char* q;
    char* p = "sweta";
    q = p++;
    q = ++p;
    printf("%s\n", q);
}
```

which gives me this:

```
eta
```